# JQuery .attr("title") undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Solved** but the answer that contained a key debugging suggestion was deleted by author. Consider case closed.

This should be really simple, but for some reason I just cannot figure it out. I need to get the value of a div's title attribute, and the jQuery code I have is:

```
var name = $('#stg'+this.id).attr('title');
```

and the div in the relevant HTML source code is:

```
<div class="stage" id="stg32432432" title="Name - desc">...</div>
```

For some odd reason, request for `attr("title")` keeps returning `undefined`, even though `attr("id")` and `attr("class")` all return expected values with no issues. What am I missing?

**Edit**: I tried debugging it with a trick suggested in a (now deleted) reply:

```
var name = $('#stg'+this.id)[0].outerHTML;
```

and lo and behold, it shows:

```
<div class="stage" id="stg32432432">...</div>
```

Something ate my title! Everything else is exactly as I expected, but the title is missing. Too bad I cannot mark that reply as correct, as I think from here on I can trace where the attributes gets annihilated.

**Update**: it turned out that a third party library used for displaying titles as fancy tooltips was stripping the titles as it processed them. Mystery resolved.

Thanks to all.

Comment: I think attr() is deprecated, try using prop() instead?

Comment: You're missing the `this.id`. What error you get?

Comment: 1) kind of weird using title in divs 2) what returns this.id?

Comment: There is the problem in your code, since both `$('#stg'+this.id).attr('title');` and `$('#stg'+this.id).prop('title');` work fine.

Comment: @tedski, sure, but still `.attr()` should handle `titles` pretty well.

Comment: As long as `this.id` is valid then it should work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/f4TrY/

Comment: makes sense. I'd debug this.id using Chrome's console.dir() to make sure you've definitely got exactly "32432432"

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the `this.id` reference is passed correctly, because I get values of the other attributes correctly, `id` and `class`.

Comment: weird, can you put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by using ('#stg'+this.id) as a selector?  That seems to be the root of the issue.  Using .attr("title") works fine.

Comment: The reason for `$('#stg'+this.id)` selector is because the action is coming from another element, not the div whose title I'm trying to get.

Comment: You should **add some more code**, full methods are best and understood a lot better. There is already enough guessing about how your js does whatever it does. So, include your (problems) javascript to question to get better answers.

Comment: You should use the `data-` prefix for custom attributes.

Comment: "mystery resolved?" which library was causing the problem? For you perhaps.... maybe somebody else is having the same issue and wants to know if it could be the same cause!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[class=stage][id^=stg]').live('mouseover', function () {
                var name = $(this).attr('title');
                $('#result').html('<h1>This ddiv title is: ' + name + '</h1>');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="result"></span>
    <div class="stage" id="stg32432432" title="Name - desc1">
        1...
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="stage" id="stg32432433" title="Name - desc2">
        2...
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="stage" id="stg32432434" title="Name - desc3">
        3...
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="stage" id="stg32432435" title="Name - desc4">
        4...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first u need to select a selector like  $('[class=stage][id^=stg]') for hat any event like click, mouseover, etc.. then inside that u can call   var name = $(this).attr('title'); then it will return the value.

Comment: thank you for help. I have figured out what the problem was, unfortunately the user who posted the answer that helped me solve it deleted it since then, so I cannot mark it as correct. Consider case closed.